# Rails 2.3: using another models named_scope inside another named_scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Let's say I have two models like so:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  named_scope :about_x :conditions => "comments.text like '%x%')"
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
end
```

How can I add a named_scope to the user model like so

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
  named_scope :comments_about_x, :includes => :comments, :comments_named_scope => :about_x
end
```

Which allows me to do

```
all_user_comments_about_x = User.comments_about_x
```

The reasoning is I often need to use the comment models about_x named scope logic but I don't want to have "comments.text like '%x%')" scattered around my code.

I hope this make sense :)

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use

```
@user.comments.about_x
```

I personally think there's no need for a `named_scope` on `user`s model.

But you can add a method instead:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   def comments_about_x
      self.comments.about_x
   end
end
```

and use

```
@user.comments_about_x
```